# Retrieve data from three separate tables and display them on one php page

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks for taking time to read my question, hopefully one of you can point me to the right direction.

My question is as follow:

In my MySQL database I have three tables containing data, my SQL code is sound and tested in phpMyAdmin SQL test. And I got an result I was happy with, the (SQL) code is:

```
SELECT e.idshow, t.c00, e.c00, e.c01, r.rating
FROM episode e 
LEFT JOIN tvshow t ON t.idshow = e.idshow 
LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.media_id = e.idShow 
AND r.media_type = 'tvshow' ORDER BY e.idFile DESC
```

Now when I want to display this result on a php page one field is empty.

I know where to find the error, because it’s the second ECHO row where I have noted that I have two c00 field names. In the SQL code the mark “t. e. and r.” are needed to separate them as in t.c00 and e.c00. But when I want to add this to the php code I got an empty field.

PHP Code:

```
echo '<td>' . $row['idshow'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['e.c00'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['c00'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['c01'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['rating'] . '</td>';
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

If I remove the e. in front of e.c00 I got a double entry displaying two times the c00 from episode instead of the data from tvshow. How can I separate them and still get an output in php. If additional information is needed I’ll supply it.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create alias for your filed like this:

```
SELECT e.idshow, t.c00 as mycolumncoo1, e.c00  as mycolumncoo2, e.c01,
```

In your php code like these:

```
echo '<td>' . $row['mycolumncoo1'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['mycolumncoo2'] . '</td>';
```

You can use alias name as per your requirement which is easily readable.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz, do you think you are the only knowledgeable person? Or do you think there are any other suitable option for this question?? You can check the timing also....I did not post it after your post also....So why downvote??

Comment: Thanks for answering, your answer was the same as the one above, tried it and it worked.

Comment: @Danny, It is ok.

Comment: if your asking me, i really didn't do it, i tryed to upvote you both but can't because of my current low level....so must have been someone else......I for one are thankfull two people did know where I was failing.

Comment: @Danny, It is ok. No problem.

Comment: Bro don't fight. @Danny please accept the Dipanwita answer so that he can get the points

Comment: @Mayank If you mean the greenie thingy, then I have set it up to Dipanwita....any who you’re both heroes in my book.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `ALIAS` for fetching the column name attached with the table name like:

```
SELECT e.idshow as col1, t.c00 as col2, e.c00 as col3, e.c01 as col4, r.rating
FROM episode e 
LEFT JOIN tvshow t ON t.idshow = e.idshow 
LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.media_id = e.idShow 
AND r.media_type = 'tvshow' ORDER BY e.idFile DESC
```

here `as col1` is an `ALIAS` given for `e.idshow` and get its value in php like:

```
$row['col1'];
```

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Comment: Will try it now

Comment: I have added as you noted the alias names and it works. Can't tell you how glad I am...thank you very much for this.

Comment: @Danny are you a free lancer ?